# Append React Highchart with Annotations after initial load of chart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

After an initial load of a chart I want to append Annotations on the go by updating the chart. 
Currently I have an update function which append data to the chart:

```
const chart = this.chart.getChart();    
const serie = this.getSerie();
chart.series[0].setData(serie.list);
```

Is there a way where I can append Annotations in a similar way?

At the moment I insert annotations into the initial chart config:

```
annotations: [{

        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 0,
        xValue:1515571888000.3572,
        yValue: 200,
        anchorX: 'left',
        anchorY: 'top',
        title: 'Annotation text',
      }]
```

But i'm interested in being able to add annotations as I update the chart.

Currently i'm using react-highcharts v. ^11.0.0 from npm.

Comment: What do you call 'annotation' ? Do you try to override your original configuration ?

Comment: Basically I want to create annotations like in this demo: 
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/annotations.

My chart is incoming live data on a time series. So as new data is fetched from the backend i update the graph with both data points and annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this **live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/gxv5f3xn/

You can use `Chart.removeAnnotation()` and `Chart.addAnnotation()` to perform dynamic updates (`Chart.update()` won't work). These methods are not docummented in the API yet.

```
  annotations: [{
    id: 'anno1',
    labels: [{
      point: 'first',
      format: '1'
    }, {
      point: 'second',
      format: '2'
    }]
  }]

(...)

  chart.removeAnnotation('anno1');

  chart.addAnnotation({
    id: 'anno2',
    labels: [{
      point: 'first',
      format: '3'
    }, {
      point: 'second',
      format: '4'
    }]
  });
```

When the series is being hidden via legend item click the error occurs - it's a bug (the official fix for it should be implemented soon). To prevent this error from happening I used modified core functions (lines 1 - 39 in the demo).